# How to Change x-axis to logarithmic in PLOTLY histogram

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, visualization

How to make x-axis of the following histogram, logarithmic?

The following code:

```py
data_list = [1,1,5,5,5,100,100]

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=data_list, nbinsx=100))

import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
py.offline.plot(fig, filename = 'test.html')
```

Produces typical histogram.
How can I change the x-axis logarithmic?

I also tried:

```py
data_list = [1,1,5,5,5,100,100]

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=data_list, nbinsx=100))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_type="log")
fig.update_xaxes(tick0=0, dtick=1, range=[0,2.5])

import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
py.offline.plot(fig, filename = 'test.html')
```

but this will result in non-logarithmic bins, and essentially, the bin at 100 disappears!

Comment: We don’t support logarithmic bins yet unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @nicolaskruchten , is there anyway to overcome this? How come we have xaxis_type = "log" without being able to change bin behavior?

Comment: You could always apply the functon log(1+x) to your data. But you'd have to make that clear. in your axis label, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above in the comments, logarithmic axes are not possible with plotly. You could try to create bins using numpy and create a bar plot with those.

Comment: And how would that look?